# Jquery On("Click") hook on links interefering with each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have two Jquery function. One function is set for hash scrolls and the other to show a modal on click. The functions are hooked to Links . I have set empty links with a `href="#"`. However my two hooks are interfering with each other. If I check for empty `hashlinks` in my first function and return a false then my second function in gallery to display Image modal is deactivated. Is there any way around this. I am sure that the obvious answer is adding some variable to my function. But I want to make a function that will check if the `href="#"` is true and not scroll but won't interfere with any other function that may be hooked by Jquery on to that link. Also why do the two hooks interfere with each other?

```
    <div><a href="/#somelinkonpage">Some text</a><div>
    <div id="gallery>
    <div class="item">
    <a class="thumbnail thumbnail-sm" href="#" rel="tooltip">
        <img src="...jpg" class="img-rounded">
    </a>
    </div>
    <div>

    //smooth scroll hashes function.
    ('a[href*=#]').on('click', function () {
                    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
                    href = href.replace(/^\//, '');
                    if (href == '#') {
                        return false;// but if I return false here modal does not work.
                    }
                    else { //smooth scroll code here }
                    return false;// if I return false here my modal function works.
                });
    //Display gallery item in modal function.
    $('#gallery').on('click', '.item a', function () {
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                    return false;
                });
```

Edit: I am puzzled by this behaviour

```
if (href == '#') {
 return false;// but if I return false here modal does not work.
 }
 else { //smooth scroll code here }
 return false;// if I return false here my modal function works.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return `false` from the event handler, it prevents the default action of the `<a>` element, **but it also stops the propagation of the event** -- that means other attached event handlers will not get executed. If you want the event handler for the smooth-scroll jump links to allow for other event handlers on those links to execute, you should just prevent the default action, but still allow the event to propagate. You can do that by calling `event.preventDefault()`, instead of returning `false`.

Start your event handlers like this:

```
$('a[href*=#]').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

And:

```
$('#gallery').on('click', '.item a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    ...
```

And don't return `false` from them.

Answer (score 0):

It may be happening because the second case uses *event delegation*, so as the first event is cancelled, it doesn't bubble for the delegation. Try this:

```
 $('#gallery .item a').on('click', function () {
     alert("hhh");
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
     return false;
 });
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
('a[href*=#]').on('click', function () {
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    href = href.replace(/^\//, '');
    if (href != '#') {
        //smooth scroll code here
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: I tried it and this dosen't work. I guess I ll just go with event.preventdefault();